# Spring Boot: Multiple datasource - Server Terminates before starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Not sure what I am missing... Need help please...

I already have an application that uses one database. Now I am adding another database. Below is the error (Server terminates while starting) I am getting when I add the extra code to get the new datasource.

**application.properties**

```
# === Existing DATA SOURCE (SQL SERVER) ===
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://mysqlserver/mydb
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=passwrd

# === New DATA SOURCE (SQL SERVER) ===  ADDING THIS DTASOURCE CODE
spring.db2Datasource.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.db2Datasource.url=jdbc:db2://mydb2server/mydb
spring.db2Datasource.username=user1
spring.db2Datasource.password=passwrd
```

Created this new class:
**DatasourceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.db2Datasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}

I have not doe any changes in my main class:
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.my.company")
public class SpringBootAFSApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootStudentApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
2019-02-11 14:43:33.323 ERROR 680 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$75412098]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'secondaryDataSource': Could not bind properties to 'HikariDataSource' : prefix=spring.db2Datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.InvalidConfigurationPropertyNameException: Configuration property name 'spring.db2Datasource' is not valid
```

**JdbcStudentRepository.java**

```
@Repository("Student")
public class JdbcStudentRepository implements StudentRepository {
    private GeneratedKeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Autowired
    public JdbcStudentRepository(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public int count(){
        return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(1) from STUDENT", Collections.emptyMap(), Integer.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prefix is wrong according [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-a-datasource)
Should be something like this:

```
db.datasource.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
db.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://mydb2server/mydb
db.datasource.username=user1
db.datasource.password=passwrd
```

And update the following line:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db.datasource")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Comment: So in that case can I have the existing jdbcTemplate which was used earlier in Repository classes unchanged ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that @SK.

Comment: I just now added the existing Repository class code

Comment: I tried, after your solution ,the server starts, but when I call any rest service I am getting error: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.

Comment: @SK looks like a new error that you have, could you please open a new question and put description detail , so let me know it , then I can help you.

Comment: I think I got it. Hikari is the default pool in spring boot 2. So I changed spring.datasource.url to spring.datasource.jdbc-url

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Hikari data source:

> Could not bind properties to 'HikariDataSource'

Based on the documentation you need to have a slightly different config:

> Also, if you happen to have Hikari on the classpath, this basic setup
>   does not work, because Hikari has no url property (but does have a
>   jdbcUrl property). In that case, you must rewrite your configuration
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> app.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
> app.datasource.username=dbuser app.datasource.password=dbpass
> app.datasource.maximum-pool-size=30
> ```

Full info and additional implementation options can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-a-datasource)

Comment: So that means I must have to make changes in existing code. I was hoping not to touch any existing code...

Comment: How do I know if I am using Hikari data source ?

Comment: Yes, from logs, it says about Hikari Pool, But I was not sure from code perspective how do I know... I will read more documentations. By the way I read nother thread that says spring boot uses Hikari as default and as you suggested I changed the to jdbc-url, that works. Thanks to you and Jonathan Johx